# Rails: Finding records that overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, overlap

I have a job model that `has_many :fonctions` and in my job model I'm creating a method to give me the number of similar fonction in all job compared to a given job.

ex: I want to compare all my job to Job1 job1 has this fonction("strategy", "management", "marketing", entrepreneurship")
another job job2 has this fonction( "strategy", "management", "data science")

So this must give me when doing (job1 & job2).size 2

for this i have this method in my job model that must do a similar job but the problem that i get this error  `undefined local variable or method for job'`

```
  def fonctions_score
    (job.fonctions.collect(&:id) & self.fonctions.collect(&:id)).size
  end
```

Update

This is the code that I'm trying now but still getting this error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

```
def fonctions_score(other_job)
  these = other_job.fonctions.collect {|f| f.id } 
  those = self.fonctions.collect {|f| f.id } 
  logger.debug these logger.debug those # should just have lists of ids 
  common = (these & those) 
  logger.debug common # should be common ids 
  common.size
end
```

in my controller I'm ordering jobs like this

```
@related_jobs = Job.all
@related_jobs.sort_by do |related_job|
  related_job.final_score
end
```

Comment: If this is a method in the Job class, then the 'job' in your fonctions_score method is undefined. It isn't self, and it isn't the class (which would be Job). You need to pass in the job to compare to self.   def fonctions_score(other_job), then compare self to the other_job. Or something like that.

Comment: so are you suggesting to me to do this   def fonctions_score(other_job)
    (other_job.fonctions.collect(&:id) & self.fonctions.collect(&:id)).id).size
  end   but this will raise this error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: Stacking or inlining functionality often hides issues.
Try:
these = other_job.fonctions.collect {|f| f.id }
those = self.fonctions.collect {|f| f.id }
logger.debug these
logger.debug those
# should just have lists of ids
common = (these & those)
logger.debug common
# should be common ids
common.size

Comment: I'm still getting the same error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)   for 
def fonctions_score(other_job)

Comment: Need more context. Update your question with code about how you are invoking all of this - the error is pretty straight forward (I think).

Comment: You can check the update to see the code that i'm trying based on your recommendation

Comment: Split the logger.debug these and logger.debug those.
What do those two debug statements show? Should just be two lists of Ids.

If not, something is amiss, or you have no shared Ids to use in the common = statement.

Comment: Actually this is the error that i'm getting wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) for def fonctions_score(other_job)

Comment: So, how do you invoke functions_score? What does you Job model class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def calculate(j1, j2)
  (j1.fonctions.pluck(:id) & j2.fonctions.pluck(:id)).size
end
```

Or

```
def calculate
   self.fonctions.count
end
```

Comment: I'm comparing a self.job to all job in my db and not only two but i have tried this     def fonctions_score(job)
    (job.fonctions.collect(&:id) & self.fonctions.collect(&:id)).size
  end
    but it give me this error  wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: Hmmm...se my answer again

Comment: this time I'm getting this error  uninitialized constant Job::Fonctions

Comment: It's a mistake. Use `Fonction` or so as your model is called.

Comment: Now it is partially working the only problem is that I'm getting 1 even for job that haven't any similar fonction to a given job is that normal?

Comment: I don't understand you want exactly. Do you want all common fonctions between two jobs or something else?

Comment: Yes I want the number of all common fonction between jobs so the problem now if a job1 has this fonction ("strategy", "management", "marketing", entrepreneurship") and job2 has this ("rails") it will return 1 even if there is no common fonction between them

Comment: You need count jobs for each fonction?

Comment: Know counting the common fonction so if I have this two job fonctions  ( "a" "b" "c" "d") and (" "f" "g") that must return 0 because there is no common fonction between the two job but what i'm actually getting is 1

Comment: So use my first method. If it's not what you want, I'm sorry but I can't help.

Comment: it is exactly what i'm using